# WPF C# .NET: Authentication with json

Tags: c#, xaml

im new.
Sorry cause im bad english first.

A problem that im making login form with json file.

First, i got that json format:

```
{
  "admin": [
    {
      "user": "admin1",
      "password": "123456"
    },
    {
      "user": "admin2",
      "password": "456789"
    }
  ]
}
```

I failed for a few way when reading json file to auth with login form. IDK where im wrong. When debug everything still fine. Please, help me, thank you.

Note: Login form contain textbox and password box (im using WPF)

Comment: What's your code for reading

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing your code that *failed for a few way when reading json file to auth with login form*.  You are much more likely to get useful answers here if you follow the suggestions from [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and share what you tried that did not work.  Good luck!